# I need TextToSpeech to work in the background, how can I do it?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-gps

I have implemented a very basic TextToSpeech in my Android app which seems to work well when the app is running in the foreground, but it doesn't play when in the background. It waits until the app returns to the foreground and plays what is in the queue. How do I achieve this for my GPS tracking app which needs to provide track feedback while the display is off?
Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    TextToSpeech textToVoice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");

        textToVoice = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    textToVoice.setLanguage(spanish);
                }
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this);
            }

            this.onLocationChanged(null);

        }else{
            this.finish();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView view  = this.findViewById(R.id.dashView);
        TextView actual = this.findViewById(R.id.actualView);

        if(location == null) {
            view.setText("0.0 Km/h");
        } else {
            //location.setAccuracy(1);
            float speedInMs = location.getSpeed();

            double currentSpeed = ( speedInMs * 3.6 );
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            df.format(currentSpeed);
            String speed = df.format(currentSpeed) + "Km/h";
            view.setText(speed);
            actual.setText(speedInMs + "m/s");


            textToVoice(speed);


            Log.d("GPS", "Location Change:" + location.getLongitude() + "," + location.getLatitude());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int i) {

    }

    public void textToVoice( String message){
        textToVoice.speak(message,
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (textToVoice != null) {
            textToVoice.stop();
            textToVoice.shutdown();
        }
        if(locationManager !=null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your use case requires a `Service`. Right now, the TTS and `LocationManager` lifecycles are linked with your `Activity`, which is the most likely component to be destroyed once the app leaves the screen.

Comment: I understand. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: I would start with the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). You probably want a foreground service. The `Activity` should bind, while it is active, but otherwise the `Service` can just exist on its own.

Comment: thanks for your help :)